# pandas .duplicated() unable to find duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe (df) that I read from an excel file using the code:

```
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('/Users/Desktop/df_1.xlsx')
df = xls_file.parse('Sheet1')
```

A shorter version of the dataframe is transposed and shown below:

```
                  0           1           2           3           4

S_Id            SB001       SB001       SB001       SB001       SB001
Reg             27548       27548       27548       27548       27548
Visit           1           2           1           2           3
Planned         5           NaN         5           NaN         NaN
Planned_2       NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
Visit_Date      15-07-22    15-10-01    15-07-22    15-10-01    16-08-01
Weight          69          70          69          70          68.3
Height          170         NaN         170         NaN         NaN
Consent         1           NaN         1           NaN         NaN
Filled_Q1       1           1           1           1           1
Filled_Q2       1           1           1           1           1
Other_Id        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
Class1_Taken    1           1           1           1           1
Class1_Date     15-07-22    15-10-01    15-07-22    15-10-01    16-08-01
Class2_Taken    1           1           1           1           1
Class2_Date     15-07-22    15-10-01    15-07-22    15-10-01    16-08-01
Class2_Time     11:05       11:55       11:05       11:55       14:05
Class3_Taken    1           1           1           1           1
Class3_Date     15-07-22    15-10-01    15-07-22    15-10-01    16-08-01
Class3_Time     10:50       10:45       10:50       10:45       13:20
Class4_Taken    1           1           1           1           1
Class5_Taken    1           1           1           1           1
Class6_Taken    1           1           1           1           1
Class7_Taken    1           1           1           1           1
Class8_Taken    0           0           0           0           0
```

Now if I use the .duplicated() method, it will generate:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
dtype: bool
```

Which is not true since 0, 2 and 1, 3 are the same.

Can anybody help here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: For your original, non-inverted DataFrame, what is the output of `df.S_Id.str.strip().duplicated()`?

Comment: If `df` is the non-transposed version, what does `df.loc[:, df.iloc[0] != df.iloc[2]]` show?

Comment: @AmiTavory it shows:
    0     False
    1      True
    2    True
    3     True
    4     True

Comment: @Hanif So my *guess* is that you have a whitespace problem in one of the other columns, but I can't tell which.

Comment: @DSM your code output the values of three columns, i.e. : Planned2  Filled_Q1  and Other_Id

Comment: Well, those are the values that aren't matching.  The NaNs are expected, but you should figure out why the Filled_Q1 values (which both look like 1) aren't equal to each other.  Maybe one's a float and one's a string, or something, or something weirder.

Comment: @AmiTavory found the culprit. It was this "Filled_Q1" column which was causing the problem. I first converted the column from "object" data type to "int64", then used strip() method to remove any spaces and now the duplicated method works.

Comment: @DSM found the culprit. It was this "Filled_Q1" column which was causing the problem. I first converted the column from "object" data type to "int64", then used strip() method to remove any spaces and now the duplicated method works.

Comment: @DSM Nice approach